# Align text center to the center of an image

Tags: html, css

I have some simple social media images, and I need the text to be in line with the center of each image. At the moment, the text is aligned to the bottom of each image, by default:

http://jsfiddle.net/uT4Ey/

CSS:

```css
.img {
  background-color: red;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  facebook
</div>
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  instagram
</div>
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  facebook
</div>
<div class="sm">
  <div class="img"></div>
  isntagram
</div>
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/uT4Ey/1/) - `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Thanks Ruddy. Are images by default an inline-block element? (The `.img` was obviously a placeholder, but it worked on `img`, too).

Comment: Yes there default is `inline-block`.

Comment: @Ruddy You just missed +5

Comment: @Mr.Alien I didn't think the answer was worth more then +1 lol Dam it.

Comment: @Ruddy Answers should be posted as answers, also, every correct answer is worth, we upvote correct answers, that's the game

Comment: @Mr.Alien Well I don't wanna play this game anymore! *crys* xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:middle;` to `img` or `div`.

```css
.img {
  background-color: red;
  height: 3em;
  width: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; /*CAN GO HERE*/
}

div {
  vertical-align: middle; /*OR HERE*/
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6Q5n/)</kbd>

You should add a `margin` to the elements after to ensure that they're not all stuck together.

Comment: Also add margin: 2px; to separate divs.

Comment: @Ruddy Yeah ha you may have commented slightly quicker too, so I would have deleted my answer!